# Start migrations from an existing db

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have a db which was created like this:

```
const UserModel = db.define('user', {
  id: { type: Sequelize.STRING, unique: true, primaryKey: true },
  firstName: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
 },
 lastName: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
 username: {
  type: Sequelize.STRING,
    unique: {
    args: true,
    msg: USERNAME_IS_TAKEN,
 },
}

UserModel.belongsToMany(UserModel, { as: 'followingUsers', through: 'Relations', foreignKey: 'followerUserId' });
```

And then run:

```
db.sync({ force: true });
```

Can I just start using migrations to add a column?

```
sequelize migration:create
```

Comment: yes you should create new migration

Comment: Keep in mind that after you added a new column in your model you cannot call the sync and execute a migration that creates the column on a new database because the migration will fail to create already existing column (created by the sync call).

Comment: I am looking for a way to start doing changes in my db, without calling sync and lose my data.